# Cypher: How to ensure (A)-[:POINTS_TO]->(B) but not (B)-[:POINTS_TO]->(A)?

Tags: neo4j

I have five nodes set up in [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qbkooe) such that each node [:POINTS_TO] all the other nodes.

How do I include an {expression} in my Cypher (2.2.0-M01) below that ensures that if (a)-[:POINTS_TO]->(b) in any point in the path that no instance of (a)<-[:POINTS_TO]-(b) also exists in any point of that path.

```
MATCH p=(a:Temp)-[r:POINTS_TO*1..5]->(b:Temp)
WHERE a=b AND {expression}
RETURN extract(n IN nodes(p)|n.name) AS pseudopath
```

Would the inclusion of such an expression mean that the query run faster than without it because of the fewer permutations, or would the compiler have to 'post-process' a filter?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to prevent neo4j from attempting to traverse cyclical paths. If so, you don't need to do anything to get that. Cypher automatically produces acyclical paths, since it does not allow the same relationship to appear twice in a result. (Technically, it *can* produce one kind of cycle -- where the the start node is the same as the end node --- but that is the only kind of cycle that is possible.)

Comment: Oh dear, I seem to have been marked down. Perhaps I should have laboured the point that there are in fact two relationships for each node pair. One in each direction. I   am aware of your point also, but perhaps you missed that tidbit?

Comment: (BTW, I did not mark you down) Why is it necessary to always have bidirectional relationships (since it does not help neo4j traverse through your data any quicker in either direction, and you end up with double the number of relationships)?

Comment: Hiya, my obviously bare-bones example is just for illustration. These relationships in the actual database carry a property value that I am accumulating in the traversal/path. The reason I have split them into one relationship per direction is in order to invert the value ie 1/value. You raise an interesting point though, but I could only be persuaded to reduce to a single (bi-directional) relationship if I had a good way of telling which direction the path had passed through the relationship. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You can use the [STARTNODE()](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.6/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-startnode) function to determine the start node of a relationship. There is also an `ENDNODE()` function.

Comment: For every relationship between two nodes you can get the head and tail.  You could carry both values as properties on the relationship and use one for tail-to-head and the other for head-to-tail.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your input.  I think I've seen the error of my ways.  I'll cut the number of relationships in half and use the STARTNODE() function to determine direction.
Cheers